# Allowing different variance of random intercepts in two different groups of subjects

Tags: r, mixed-model, heteroscedasticity, lme4-nlme

Is there a way to specify two different random intercept terms for two sub-groups of subjects within a single mixed model? The reason why I'm interested is that it seems that the inter-personal variability of one group of subjects on my task is greater than the inter-personal variability of the other. I'm using lmer and currently specifying the subject factor as a random intercept, which pools all my participants into a single estimate, but I would like to have two separate estimates for the two sub-groups.

Comment: Would a random slope in the group indicator do the job?

Comment: It seems that it would not because I'm getting information about the average performance difference between the groups if I specify Group as a fixed factor. If I put Group in a random factor (1|Group), I don't seem to get an answer about the variability of group intercepts from the lmer summary.

Comment: I'm assuming you have some grouping in the data (e.g. repeated measurements on people) other than the two subgroups you were talking about. Call _that_ grouping `ID` and call the binary subgroup indicator `G`. Then, what I was suggesting was something like putting a `(1+G|ID)` term in your model.

Comment: And then the variance of the slope estimate would be indicative of the differences between the variances between the groups?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2):

Using the "weights" argument in R's nlme you can allow for separate variances for each level of a grouping variable (heterogeneous variability).

For examples see:

https://quantdev.ssri.psu.edu/sites/qdev/files/ILD_Ch06_2017_MLMwithHeterogeneousVariance.html
https://fukamilab.github.io/BIO202/03-C-heterogeneity.html